# Terminology for "jump to code"

Tags: ide, terminology

When writing source code, in many IDEs and editors you can

- jump to the method declaration
- jump to the class declaration
- etc.

Is there any keyword or technical term which describes this feature?

Comment: It may be broad, but what about Navigate?

Comment: Yes.  It's "jump to".  It literally implies that your cursor will immediately leap from whereever it is in the tree, to the code you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Saturisk, _Code Navigation_ was the term I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Code Navigation* is the term is was looking for.